# unable to compile maven project diamond operator is not supported in -source 1.5 (use -source 7 or higher to enable diamond operator)

Tags: java, maven

I am using java 8 and configured all the things but after updating maven project in automatically reverted to java 7 and saying above error. Also did all configuration like project facets and compiler version.

Comment: i am unable to compile maven project. when i build project then i get compilation failed diamond operator is not supported in -source 1.5 (use -source 7 or higher to enable diamond operator). and also  getting Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project MailBlaster: Compilation failure

Answer (score 0):

You can set maven compiler plugin as below

```
<plugin>
   <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>3.1</version>
     <configuration>
       <source>1.8</source>
       <target>1.8</target>
     </configuration>
</plugin>
```